# How to set the background of the android application?

Tags: android, background

I want to change the background of my App's Activity.

Now that is available in black I want to change that with some images or themes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to @Ryan:

In the layout for your activities, you can also add the attribute

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

to set a background color. You can also introduce a custom resource `/res/values/colors.xml` in which you can declare custom colors. One such file might look like:

```
<resources>
<color name="fire_brick_red">#B0171F</color>
</resources>
```

You then introduce these in XML as follows:

```
android:background="@color/fire_brick_red"
```

Answer (score 37):

Add a `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme` attribute to your application tag in the manifest file with the theme you want to use. This will prevent the default "black" background to be drawn if you only set a background in your Activity/Fragment layout file.

You declared it in a **style.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme">
<!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
-->
</style>
</style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
...
<application
    android:name="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
...
```

Comment: It's only correct answer. It set **application** not **actiivty** background.

Comment: yes it is work perfectly. But I did not get idea why we need to inherit from `AppBaseTheme`? What is the difference between `<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme">`

Answer (score 3):

Add the background attribute to your window's xml layout.  Example:

```
<LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/yourbackgroundimage" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would try to do it in xml like Sk9 suggests, but programmatically at runtime you can do

> ```
> setBackgroundColor(int color)
> ```

or

> ```
> setBackgroundResource(int resourceID)
> ```

Source:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: of which class is this method?