# Change background image in android studio

Tags: android, xml, background

I am new to android programming, but i have a problem.

I don't know why, if i test my app with emulator without a background image it works, and if i try it with a background image my app crashes.. it says "unfortunately MyApp has stopped working".

I have put my image.png into the `drawable` folder and i used `android:background="@drawable/image"` into the xml file of the activity.

It gives me this error

```
07-03 19:25:06.084    7491-7491/com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker, PID: 7491
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker/com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:389)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2113)
            at com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6116)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:389)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2113)
            at com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6116)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:389)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2113)
            at com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6116)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1073)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2633)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2538)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3920)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:572)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:389)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2113)
            at com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6116)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

Thank you very much !

This is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/image">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your xml file?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479977/how-to-set-the-background-of-the-android-application)

Comment: It looks like you've cut off the most important part of the log at the start

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM

Its inflation error because your images is too high/high quality.
try to lower the quality of your image, so it will make no error.
hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This is an inflation error, usually caused when you are trying to inflate wrong thing (like Fragment instead of support.v4.Fragment) so check your code.